# TypeORM Postgres - Query 10K rows takes several minutes to finish from code, way faster from pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have an app using TypeORM and NestJS.

Whenever I query a collection with a WHERE clause to a relational field, it takes several minutes to execute and return the results.

When I query from within pgAdmin it it way faster. Generally, I dont think fetching 10K rows of a table should take that long. I have done with way more data using mongodb in much quicker manner.

Is this typeORM related or am I doing something wrong?

```js
    const assetResponse = await getRepository(Asset).find({ where: { collection: collection } })
```

Asset Entity class

```js
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  asset_id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  token_id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  name: string;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  num_sales: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  background_color: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  image_url: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  image_preview_url: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  image_thumbnail_url: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  image_original_url: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  animation_original_url: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  external_link: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  description: string;

  @Column('simple-json', { nullable: true })
  asset_contract: AssetContract;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  permalink: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Collection, (collection: Collection) => collection.assets, { onDelete: "CASCADE" })
  collection: Collection;
```

Comment: I would enable logging the query the TypeORM is making and run it against a SQL analyzer to see if there are any pitfalls in what it is doing. Generally, TypeORM tends to write some pretty inefficient queries

Answer (score 0):

You could use raw SQL by using getManager

```
async findAll(collection : string) {
    return await getManager().query(`
    SELECT * FROM "Asset" WHERE collection = '${collection}'
    `);
  }
```